# ¿Una clase interna podria considerarse atributo de la clase externa?

Tags: java

Si es así, porque no es posible declarar un tipo  de la clase interna haciendo uso de una instancia de la clase externa en vez de acceder directamente al nombre de clase? así:

```
class Externa{

  class Interna{

  }
}

class Principal{
  public static void main(String [] args){

     Externa ex = new Externa();
     ex.Interna = new ex.Interna();

  }
}
```

en vez de:

```
    class Externa{

  class Interna{

  }
}

class Principal{
  public static void main(String [] args){
     Externa ex = new Externa();
     Externa.Interna = new ex.Interna();

  }
}
```

Se que es como cuando declaramos una clase, obviamente debemos poner el tipo no el valor, pero una clase interna esta declarada dentro de otra y eso me confunde un poco, eso significa que puede accederse a ese tipo a través de la clase contenedora osea a a través de una instancia así como cuando se declaran atributos de la clase como enteros, otros objetos etc. ¿Porque no puede hacerse de esa forma si es considerada un atributo?

¿Porque debemos declararlo de manera NombreDeLaClase.ClaseInternaNombre? y no usando una instancia

Estaba tratando de verlo de la forma en que al ser una declaración de tipos debo especificar el tipo primero y el subtipo (que es el nombre de la clase interna) después y así me parece lógico pero me choca el hecho de que este adentro de otra clase, y lo veo como si fuese un miembro que se usara en una instancia

Lo veo como si es un tipo definido en la clase, el instanciar un objeto crea un ámbito en el cual hay tipos definidos y se puede acceder a ellos a través de la variable de instancia y si hay una clase que tiene definida otra clase adentro pienso que significa que ese tipo (la clase interna) solo sera accedida a través de la instancia del objeto que crea el ámbito del cual es parte la clase interna osea que ese tipo definido solo se define cuando existe un objeto de la clase externa :/....lo que significa que solo a travez del ambito creado por la instancia se puede acceder al tipo y asi poder crear un objeto de ese tipo pero no es asi como funciona, y necesito que alguien pudiese explicarme el porque no debe de ser asi y el porque debe de ser:

`NombreDeLaClase.NombreDeLaClaseInterna nombreDeLaVariable;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre la cuestión de "¿se puede considerar atributo?" yo diría que la idea del nombre es más similar a la de un *package* que a la de un atributo de una clase. En todo caso la analogías pueden ser traicioneras.

Si nos centramos en "porqué no puedo definir la clase como [nombre de variable].[nombre de clase interna]",  la verdad es que la respuesta simplemente es **porque la especificación lo dice así**.

Pero podemos ver algunas complicaciones relacionadas con tu propuesta; el punto importante es que **las clases internas no se heredan**.

```
public class Externa {
   class Interna {}
}

public class Externa2 extends Externa {
}

Externa2.Interna in; // Error de compilación.
```

pero, si tienes una variable:

```
Externa ex;
```

puedes hacer

```
ex = new Externa2();
```

y, con tu propuesta, podrías hacer

```
ex.Interna in;
```

¡Estás definiendo una variable de un tipo que no existe, y el compilador no lo puede detectar! A Java le gusta que el compilador detecte todo lo que se pueda detectar.

Más divertido aún, nos olvidamos de *Externa2* y añadimos:

```
public class Externa3 extends Externa {
   class Interna {} // Una nueva clase diferente!!!!
}
```

Y haces

```
Externa ex = esJueves ? new Externa() : new Externa3();
ex.Interna in;
```

Es imposible determinar en tiempo de compilación el tipo de *in*...

Answer (score 1):

## Más o menos

Una clase interna es una clase en todo su derecho, con su lógica propia y atributos propios, que incluso puede ser instanciada si no es privada, pero que **lógicamente depende de la instancia** su clase externa.

Al definir una clase como interna de otra, encapsulas un comportamiento esperado en la clase externa en su clase interna.

Por lo que sí, puedes verla como un atributo porque está declarada dentro del ámbito de la clase externa y (como ya has comprobado) no puedes instanciarla sin instanciar antes la clase externa, pero al ser una clase con todas las de la ley, su tipo tiene que estar bien diferenciado. Por eso se utiliza la nomenclatura `Externa.Interna`

Puedes investigar un ejemplo muy útil en la propia api de java, el [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Iterator es una interfaz que es implementada en forma de clase interna para todos los tipos que son iterables (List, Set, Deque...)

Cada una tiene un iterator interno, propio, que implementa esta interfaz. Éste es el que se encarga de encapsular la forma de iterar y qué hacer para cada elemento en esa iteración.

Comment: *pero que lógicamente depende de la instancia su clase externa.* A no ser que sea *static class...*. Además, creo que el OP entiende que el tipo tiene que estar bien diferenciado, pero la pregunta es porqué no se puede diferenciar usando la variable de tipo *Externa* en vez de usar el nombre de la clase. Pero en general las cosas que dices son bastante acertadas.

Comment: @SJuan76 el OP habla de clase interna, diferenciación hecha en los tutoriales de java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html . En cuanto a lo que pregunta el OP, creo que queda claro el por qué se diferencia el tipo usando el de la clase externa. Por supuesto te animo a responder tú también puesto que me parece una pregunta interesante  sobre la que todos podemos mejorar nuestros conocimientos sobre este tema.

Comment: Ok, tienes razón sobre ese punto.

Answer (score 0):

en tu ejemplo, la clase `interna` esta declarada dentro del ambito de clase `externa`. Por lo tanto, NO EXISTE fuera de dicho entorno. Ninguna clase conoce dicha definicion, por lo que nunca vas a poder crear DESDE FUERA de clase externa una clase `interna`.

Ahora bien,

si tuvieras un metodo en clase Externa, que hiciera algo como:

```
class Externa{
  class Interna{
  }

  public void instancia() {
     interna in = new Interna();
  }
}
```

Aqui SI puedes instanciar un objeto de tipo `Interna` ya que estamos dentro del ambito de definicion (en este caso, estamos dentro de clase `externa`)